# Generate a sufficient secret for JWT NodeJS Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, jwt

I've been looking at implementing JWT for the first time using jsonwebtoken (https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken). For that, I need a secret value.

Is there a recommended command, or site, to generate a sufficiently good one?

I found this page (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95972/what-are-requirements-for-hmac-secret-key) which goes into detail about how long a secret should be (the answer seems to be a 256-bit), but where do you *get* one from? :)

*Else* it seems the other option would be to use a public/private key pair. They seem to prefer that approach on this guide I found: https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/json-web-token-jwt-the-right-way-of-implementing-with-node-js-65b8915d550e since that guy says he started off using a string and then switched to using a key pair. *However* the complication is this will be running on Lambda so I would ideally like the secrets (string or key) to be in environment variables. *Not* kept as files. But if you put a certificate in an environment variable, I wonder if AWS will strip out newlines and so screw it up when Node tries to work with it. So I'm thinking a secret string would be simpler - as long as it is sufficiently strong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is what I did when implementing HapiJS with JWT2. I generated a key based on the documentation they provided. According to [their repo](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2#generating-your-secret-key), this is one of the simplest ways to generate a secure key to sign against for JWT.

`node -e "console.log(require('crypto').randomBytes(256).toString('base64'));"`

I don't think you have to use asymmetric key authentication with public/private keys for JWT. In simplest forms, when a user logs into your system, they are given a hash of user data. On the client side, you provide that hash in the authorization header with each request. The server will check the hash to verify integrity. Since you have the key that you hashed against, it's highly unlikely that they will be able to create a forged hash.

Check out [this link](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2/issues/48) to the GitHub issue where they discuss generating keys for [Hapi-auth-JWT2](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2).